# Using User Defined Function in R Shiny that returns multiple values I want to output

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

So my goal here is to create a Shiny app that accepts user text inputs, then runs a user-defined function on a button click that takes those inputs as parameters. After running the function, displays the functions multiple outputs (a plot, 3 dataframes). When clicking the button, the function does not run in my console. Once that problem is solved, I need to figure out how to access the items of the list that the function returns to use those as output items.

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)



ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
  textInput(inputId = 'specify_team', label = "Specify Team", placeholder= "Team"),
  textInput(inputId = 'specify_player', label = "Specify Player", placeholder= "Player"),
  textInput(inputId = 'specify_year', label = "Specify Year", placeholder= "Year")),

  mainPanel(
  actionButton("run", "run code"),

  plotOutput('shotchart'),
  dataTableOutput('overall'),
  dataTableOutput('area'),
  dataTableOutput('zone')
))
)
```

Define Function (done outside of sever, not sure if this is right) - function returns a list with its outputs I want to use from it.

```
bball <-  function (specify_team, specify_player, specify_year){
. . .
. . .
newlist <<- list(overall_summary,shot_zone_summary,shot_area_summary,end_plot)
}
```

Server

```
 #store reactive values
   specify_team <<- reactive({input$specify_team})
   specify_player <<- reactive ({input$specify_player})
   specify_year <<- reactive ({input$specify_year})

   vals <-reactiveValues(area = NULL,
                         zone = NULL,
                         overall = NULL,
                         shotchart = NULL)

   data <- eventReactive(input$run, {
   bball_ret <<-bball(specify_team,specify_player,specify_year)

   })

   output$area = renderDataTable(data[3] ) #newlist[3] #shot_area_summary 
   output$zone = renderDataTable(data[2] ) #newlist[2] #shot_zone_summary
   output$overall = renderDataTable(data[1] ) #newlist[1] #overall_summary
   output$shotchart = renderPlot(data[4] ) #newlist[4] #end_plot
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Since `specify_team`, `specify_player` and `specify_year` are reactive values, I recommend passing them to your function as `specify_team()`, `specify_player()` and `specify_year()`. Inside your function `bball`, you should return the list rather than assigning it to a variable: drop the `newlist <<-` part.

Comment: @Bas appreciate the tip on passing in reactive values - that solved my issue along with just sourcing in my bball function from another script file. With returning that list at the end of my bball function, how do I access those list items after the function is called on the button click to use in rendering for outpiut?

Comment: With returning that list at the end of my bball function, how do I use those values (overall_summary,shot_zone_summary,shot_area_summary,end_plot) and make those outputs update with a new call?

Comment: Glad it worked! You should probably be able to obtain the individual elements by removing `bball_ret <<-`, and using `data()[[1]]`, `data()[[2]]`, etc.